# How to convert Finite Automata to Regular Grammar

Tags: grammar, finite-automata

Can you please help me to convert this Finite Automata to Regular Grammar?

```
          a    b
____________________
--> q1 |  q2   q1
    q2 |  q1   q3
    q3 |  q4   q3
<-- q4 |  q3   q1
____________________
```

Comment: Ok I guess that is homework so the usual question: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Some hints - ignore the b from q4 to q1 at first, and try to see how you can translate the a-loops between q1/q2 and q3/q4, the other b-parts should be straight-forward - finally try to see how you can attach the b (it will be some kind of repetition - so a kleene-star something ...)

Comment: Hi Carsten,Thank you for your comment. Here is my solution, but I'm not sure if it is correct: 
S--> aA | bS;
A--> aS | bB;
B--> bB | aC | a;
C--> aB.

Comment: I don't understand why can I ignore the b from q4 to q1.

Answer (score 0):

First we convert the given data into equivalent Finite automata

[image: Here is the Finite Automata for given data]

Then from the FA we will get
Initial state -q1,final state -q4,
Non-terminals(V)-{q1,q2,q3,q4}(usually non-terminals are denoted with capital letters)
terminals-(T)-{a,b},
start symbol-q1

By using FA  we write the production rules in regular grammer

```
P: {  q1--> a q2    
      q1--> b q1
      q2--> a q1
      q2--> b q3
      q3--> a q4
      q3--> b q3
      q3--> a
      q4--> a q3
      q4--> b q1 }
```

Therefore  given FA is converted to regular grammer